# How can merge conflicts be avoided when different methods (etc.) are added at the same location?

Tags: git, merge, conflict, git-merge-conflict

Preface: this is not a general question about merge conflicts, but a very specific case that keeps bugging me. It is quite trivial, but it does amount to a (slight) hassle often enough to stand out. I am not concerned about general merging, this is just about saving a few seconds here and there for very mechanical conflict resolution, by avoiding said conflict in the first place. I am also absolutely aware that this is *not* a "git problem" or something like that.

That said, assume we have a source file of a class:

```
class Xyz
    ...
    ...
   def last_method
      ...
   end
end
```

This starts out identical in `master` and several feature branches. Now, as we implement our features, we add more methods to this class:

Branch 1:

```
class Xyz
    ...
    ...
    def last_method
        ...
    end

    def new_method1
        ...
    end
end
```

Branch 2:

```
class Xyz
    ...
    ...
    def last_method
        ...
    end

    def new_method2
        ...
    end
end
```

The new methods are not related and will happily coexist when both branches are merged back to `master`.

Obviously this will lead to a merge conflict. The reason is clear - we changed the source file at exactly the same spot, and obviously git cannot (and should not) magically decide for us that this is not a "real" conflict; git would have to chose which of the methods should be placed first, etc.

One way to avoid the conflict would be to insert the new methods at different places in the file (assuming the order does not matter), but we really don't want to spend much effort (or any at all, actually) to mentally keep track where to insert stuff or what happens in other features.

The question, then: is there another way, maybe some coding convention, that you are regularly applying, which somehow avoids this merge conflict?

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question. However, there are ways of mitigating the problem, under certain conditions.

In the ideal case, at the time of designing a class, you decide what it's going to be made of (variables, methods, etc.), and you can already choose appropriate names for those. In that case, you should write *stubs* of those methods in the commit that introduces the class.

Those stubs will then act as "anchors" for a line-based version control system such as Git:

```rb
class MyClass

    def initialize
        # TODO
    end

    def get_ID
        # TODO
    end

    def set_ID
        # TODO
    end
end
```

After this "first" commit, different contributors are free to change the body of different methods: in my example, Alice can implement `get_ID` and Bob can implement `set_ID` without fear of running into a merge conflict further down the road, because the `def` and `end` lines of each method are already present in the original commit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I appreciate that you mentioned "under certain conditions". Those unfortunately don't apply - in my case it's agile/BDD driven development where we are doing quite the opposite; i.e., we do not have unused placeholder code or even "todo" implementations of empty methods (at least not in `master`).

Comment: @Ekkehard That's all I can think of. It's easy, as a human being, to see that different methods added by different contributors shouldn't cause a merge conflict, but from the diff3 algorithm is not sophisticated enough to detect that; as far as it's concerned, different lines added at the same location => conflict.